# optimisation xml handling within vb.net application

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have this snippet , i need to optimize it to be faster :

```
Dim lst = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes Select ID = t.item("ID").outerxml).Distinct().ToList()
       Parallel.For(0, lst.Count, Sub(i)
         Dim P As XmlElement = GetElement(lst(i))
       Dim ls = (From t In DocElet.ChildNodes Where t.item("ID").innerText = P.InnerText Select t)
         Parallel.ForEach(ls, Sub(D)
         Dim verif_date As String = D.Item("DAD").InnerText
        Sej.ID = D.Item("ID").InnerText
         End Sub)
            End Sub)
```

this isthe Xml structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PatientData>
<Sejour><ID></ID><DAD></DAD></Sejour>
  </PatientData>
```

I'm asking how can i fix my code because it takes a lot of time ( 50 sec) in the case where the list contains 20000 elements?

Comment: To get better assistance you should describe what you want to achieve, and What is structure of your XML.

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: OK, ... now, how do you want to process this XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OuterXml`/`InnerText` methods may be slow as they need to walk XML tree and build new XML/text from all elements.

It looks like you are looking for matches value of some `<ID>` nodes. If such nodes contain just single value and not sub-trees use [XmlElement.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Side note: accessing XML from multiple threads with `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` is not guaranteed to work correctly as these classes are not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) . I'm using `Parallel.For/Parallel.ForEach` instead the normal loop to minimize the execution time

Comment: @Lamloumi Your call... there are many ways to write randomly behaving code and non-synchronized multithreaded access to non-thread-safe objects is one of the ways. I'd prefer to `throw InvlaidOperation()` :) as first line since it makes code even faster and guarantees the same behavior all the time unlike hoping for multithreaded access to `XmlElement` would work correctly despite information on MSDN.

Comment: `there are many ways to write randomly behaving code and non-synchronized multithreaded access to non-thread-safe objects` . Can you give an example

Comment: @Lamloumi - you've already provided sample in the question - not sure what exactly you are looking for in "can you give an example". Since `XmlElement` and related classes is not documented thread safe it means there is no particular guarantees that code work the same way on the data between different runs. Here is [XmlDocument thread safety](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703080/is-reading-from-an-xmldocument-object-thread-safe) post.