# Why XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) calls XmlNode.RemoveAll()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

When the SimpleClass.LoadXml is called, the following exception is thrown

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at
>   System.Xml.XmlNode.RemoveChild(XmlNode oldChild)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlNode.RemoveAll()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)

The `SimpleClass` looks like this

```
public static class SimpleClass 
{
     static XmlDocument _myXmlDocu = new XmlDocument();

     /// <summary>
        /// Method to load embedded XML data file from assembly.
        /// </summary>
        private static void LoadXml()
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNameSpace.data.xml"));
            _myXmlDocu.Load(reader);
        }
}
```

I do not understand why `XmlNode.RemoveAll()` is called when I call `_myXmlDocu.Load(reader)`??

The code is executed in an ASP.NET WebForms app on IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XmlDocument.Load()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs,e813c423a1251709,references) calls [`XmlNode.RemoveAll()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlNode.cs,1e735689fb582adf) in order to remove all existing data from the XML document before reading the XML file because `Load()` *replaces* the current contents of the `XmlDocument` with the newly read XML data, rather than merging or appending them.

A better question is, why would `RemoveAll()` throw an exception?  The most likely reason is due to multithreading: two threads of your process are attempting to initialize your `_myXmlDocu` static variable at once, and are stepping on each other.  (According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instance members of `XmlDocument` are *not* guaranteed to be thread safe).  It appears you are trying to cache the XML from a manifest resource stream as a single instance in memory, reading it only once.  If so, you should follow the instructions here to initialize your cache in a thread-safe manner: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

For instance, here is a simple thread-safe way to cache the XML resource inside `SimpleClass`.  It loads the resource in the static constructor for the class:

```
public static class SimpleClass
{
    const string resourceName = "MyNameSpace.data.xml";

    static XmlDocument _myXmlDocu = null;

    static SimpleClass()
    {
        _myXmlDocu = new XmlDocument();
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
        {
            _myXmlDocu.Load(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XmlDocument GetResourceData()
    {
        return _myXmlDocu;
    }
}
```

This loads the XML resource file once, the first time a static method or property of `SimpleClass` is used.  It corresponds to the "Fourth version" of the singleton pattern from the linked article.

If your `SimpleClass` is actually not simple and has many unrelated static properties and methods, requiring you to defer loading the XML until it is actually about to be used, consider using the fifth or sixth versions of the pattern in the linked article.

Incidentally, while write operations to `XmlDocument` (like `Load()` ) are definitely not thread safe, read operations are also not *documented* to be thread safe.  See [*Is reading from an XmlDocument object thread safe?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703080/is-reading-from-an-xmldocument-object-thread-safe) for a discussion.  You might want to reconsider whether this caching strategy makes sense.