# IXMLDocument in component accessed from different threads: where to call CoInitializeEx?

Tags: xml, multithreading, delphi, txmldocument

I am writing a threadsafe component which logs xml string to a file.  The component's public method will be called from many different (types of) threads. To simplify, in the example below the component only has to return an XML string from parameters.

My question is: can I avoid having to call `CoInitializeEx` in each thread?  I want to keep the `CoInitializeEx()` and `CoUnitialize` and the `IXMLDocument` stuff inside the component so the callers don't need to worry about this.  Is there a safe way for the threads to call that public function which would create a `TXMLDocument` on each call they make, even though the CoInitializeEx() would be called from the component (TMyLogger) which does not run in the calling thread?
I'm not sure calling this function from multiple threads would corrupt the XMLDocument or not (since it's an interface).

Example to illustrate what I want to do:

```
TMyLogger = class(TComponent)
    public
        function logLineAsXml(const aLineName: String; const aAttribNames: Array of String; const aAttribValues: Array of String): String;
end;

function TMyLogger.logLineAsXml(const aLineName: String; const aAttribNames: Array of String; const aAttribValues: Array of String): String;
var
  doc: IXMLDocument;
  node: IXMLNode;
  I: LongInt;
begin
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Nil);
  try
    doc.XML.Clear;
    doc.Active := True;
    node := doc.AddChild(aLineName);
    for I := Low(aAttribNames) to High(aAttribNames) do begin
      node.Attributes[aAttribNames[I]] := aAttribValues[I];
    end;
    Result := node.XML;
  finally
    doc := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
    while not Terminated do begin
        DM.logger.logLineAsXml('log',['attrib1','[attrib2'],['x','y']); //must save line as  <log attrib1="x" attrib2="y"/>
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Each thread using COM needs to initialize (by calling CoInitializeEx). You can't avoid it.

Comment: @OndrejKelle and if each thread calls CoInitializeEx, would the function TMyLogger.logLineAsXml be threadsafe?  Or is there a risk that `TXMLDocument.Create` would return the instance of an existing TXMLDocument?

Comment: Depends. If the server supports free-threaded apartments you can use it and do your own thread synchronization. With single-threaded apartment interface references need to be marshaled across threads, either by implementing IMarshal yourself or delegating to the free threaded marshaler (CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: _Or is there a risk that TXMLDocument.Create would return the instance of an existing TXMLDocument?_ No.

Comment: About thread safety of [TXMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703080/is-reading-from-an-xmldocument-object-thread-safe) and [MSXML/IXMLDocument](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/680b593b-08ee-4b53-8ae5-a03641b1ad18/is-the-xmldocument-threadsafe?forum=xmlandnetfx). Executive summary: They are not thread safe, and so should not be called from multiple threads.

Comment: For this specific task, a logger, I would make a thread that accepts your log messages in an XML-agnostic way. Only the log thread itself needs access to the XML document that is persisted. It can store the log messages in a thread safe list or queue, or protect it using critical sections. The thread itself when running, can offload the list contents to the XML document. That will also prevent your application from slowing down too much because of the slowness of TXMLDocument (especially if you want to persist it as well).

Comment: Ok, in all fairness I wouldn't log to XML at all, and if I would, I probably wouldn't use XMLDocument, but if I would, I would do it like I described in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints everyone.

I made the thread the only instance that will access the `TXMLDocument`, the callers will add the data to the threads queue which will process it sequentially.